# Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 10.1 Content Migration

Tags: upgrade, content-migration

Is there any tool to migrate content from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 10.1.

I am creating packages from Sitecore 8.2 and installing in Sitecore 10.1 but that process is very slow and is taking alot of time.

Is there any tool available to automate the content migration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the Express Migration tool  https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool.aspx if you need the best performance. You can skip file and configuration migration steps and migrate core or/and master DBs only. It works directly with SQL, as a result, it provides the best content migration performance.
Despite this tool officially supporting up to 9.0 migration it should work fine for higher versions, I've successfully migrated content to 9.2 without any known issues for several sites.

Answer (score 2):

While there are other options available as seen by viewing questions with the content migration tag, Sitecore PowerShell Extensions may be a good option.

With the following you can do a lot of content in a short time. Requires SPE and Unicorn to already be in use.

https://github.com/michaellwest/Spe-Content-Migrator